# Getting the variable value from the json query

Tags: jquery, json

I'm struggling to get the value of a JSON query?

I have tried many solutions online, but non of them worked. All I want to do is get the value `priceEnd` from the JSON query and display it in the `itemPrice` div (which refreshed every 2 seconds or so). What am I doing wrong?

```
{"priceEnd":"965.00","numberOfBids":"103"}

setInterval(function() {

///get the bid incriments
$.ajax({
    url : 'itemPrice.php?itemID=123',                         
    type: 'post',                   
    dataType:'json',                   
    success : function(data) {  
        console.log(data);
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
});

var priceEnd = data.priceEnd;

$('#itemPrice').html(priceEnd);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: "i have tried many solutions" what did you tried? See also [ask]

Comment: It's **asynchronous** !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Doesn't jQuery parse the JSON automatically?

Comment: @Blender yes, it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a dataType of JSON, the parsing is done automatically, and since ajax is asynchronous you can't use the data until it is returned in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'itemPrice.php',                         
    type: 'post',
    data: {itemID: '123'},                   
    dataType:'json',                   
    success : function(data) {  
        var priceEnd = data.priceEnd;
        $('#itemPrice').html(priceEnd);
    }
});
```